# ORA-01403 - no data found -- even though cursor SELECT statement is running fine

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
declare
CURSOR C1 IS
    Select to_date(DateRange,'dd-mm-rrrr') DateRange 
    from (select to_date('01-JAN-2016','DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level as DateRange
      from    DUAL
      where   (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level) <= LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('31-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR'))
      connect by level<=366)
where substr(to_char(DateRange,'DAY'),1,3) in ('SUN','SAT');
begin
   if not c1%ISopen
      then
      open C1;
end if;
  dbms_output.put_line("Cursor is created and number of affected rows are: " || c1%rowcount);
  close c1;
end;
/
```

Even though the select statement used in Creating Cursor is running fine, but when i am trying to execute the code it is throwing error -- ORA-01403 - no data found

Answer (score 2):

You open the cursor, but do not fetch it.
From documentation:

> %ROWCOUNT Attribute A cursor attribute that can be appended to the
>   name of a cursor or cursor variable. When a cursor is opened,
>   %ROWCOUNT is zeroed. Before the first fetch, cursor_name%ROWCOUNT
>   returns 0. Thereafter, it returns the number of rows fetched so far.
>   The number is incremented if the latest fetch returned a row.

The code should be something like this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C1
   IS
      SELECT TO_DATE (DateRange, 'dd-mm-rrrr') DateRange
        FROM (    SELECT TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + LEVEL
                            AS DateRange
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE (TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + LEVEL) <=
                            LAST_DAY (TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR'))
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366)
       WHERE SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (DateRange, 'DAY'), 1, 3) IN ('SUN', 'SAT');

   a   DATE;
BEGIN
   IF NOT c1%ISOPEN
   THEN
      OPEN C1;
   END IF;

   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO a;

      EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      'Cursor is created and number of affected rows are: ' || c1%ROWCOUNT);

   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is not right. Replace `to_date` with `to_char`.

```
declare
CURSOR C1 IS
    select to_char(DateRange,'dd-mm-rrrr') DateRange   --replaced to_date with to_char
    from 
      (
        select to_date('01-JAN-2016','DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level as DateRange
        from    DUAL
        where   (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level) <= LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('31-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR'))
        connect by level<=366
      )
    where substr(to_char(DateRange,'DAY'),1,3) in ('SUN','SAT');
begin
   if not c1%ISopen
      then
      open C1;
end if;
  dbms_output.put_line("Cursor is created and number of affected rows are: " || c1%rowcount);
  close c1;
end;
/
```

From inner query you are returning a `date` but in the main `select` clause you are using `to_date` on a `date` which might be why you are not getting desired result.

Comment: Hi @Utsav .. Thanks for the reply. But i have checked the select statement one by one i.e. i have checked the inner query and then the complete query and it is running fine.

Comment: Not possible. Try running your complete select query once. It will give error. Then try replacing outermost `to_date` to `to_char` as I gave in the example and then see again. You will understand what I am saying

Comment: I am running the following query and is working fine :    Select to_date(DateRange,'dd-mm-rrrr') DateRange 
 from (select to_date('01-JAN-2016','DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level as DateRange
          from    DUAL
          where   (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR') - 1 + level) <= LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('31-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-RRRR'))
          connect by level<=366)
    where substr(to_char(DateRange,'DAY'),1,3) in ('SUN','SAT');   
Please let me know if i have any attachment option here so that i can provide it to you or your skype id?

Comment: I am in office so can't do much. Try replacing outermost to_date to to_char as I mentioned in answer and then create your pl/sql block again. Let me know if you still get error.

Comment: I think you are not getting it .. i have told multiple times that my SELECT statement is working FINE .. Kindly let me know if you have any idea on Cursor error or not .. else no issue .. thanks for your help ..